# In Java why do I get an error message saying I need an else if?

Tags: java, if-statement, compiler-errors

So I have this huge project due within 6 hours, and although I haven't coded all the files that will be read I'm setting up all of the if statements.  You see I'm making a database where the user types in 3 numbers, and in return will get a file read as out put. Everything seems fine thus far except for this one else shown at the bottom:

```
 if (choose == 4) //enemies from the original Kingdom Hearts II
           {
            System.out.println("Please select the enemy race you wish to view:");
            System.out.println("1. Heartless");
            System.out.println("2. Nobodies");
            int enemies_4 = kH.nextInt();

        if (enemies_4 == 1) //Allows the user to select which kinds of Heartless to view from Kingdom Hearts II.
        {
            System.out.println("Please type the number which corresponds to the Heartless enemy type.");
            System.out.println("1. Pureblood");
            System.out.println("2. Emblem");
            System.out.println("3. Gummi");
            int heartless_4 = kH.nextInt();

            if (heartless_4 = 1) //allows the user to view Pureblood Heartless from KH2
            {

            }

            if (heartless_4 == 2) //allows the user to view the Emblem Heartless in KH2
            {

            }

            else
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter a number which corresponds to one of the Heartless types KH2.");
            }
        }


        if (enemies_4 == 2) //allows the user to view all of the Nobodies in KH2
        {
            System.out.println("Please type the number which corresponds to the Nobody enemy type.");
            System.out.println("1. Lower");
            System.out.println("2. Gummi");
            int nobodies_4 = kH.nextInt();

            if (nobodies_4 == 1) //Gives the selection of the Lower Nodies in Kingdom Hearts II.
            {

            }

            if (nobodies_4 == 2) //Gives the selection of the Gummi Nobodies, which are ONLY in Kingdom Hearts II
                                //(as well as the Final Mix version of it).
            {

            }

            if (nobodies_4 == 3) //Give the selection of all he members of Organization XIII which appear in
                                    //Kingdom Hearts II.
            {

            }

            else
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter a number which corresponds to one of the Nobody types KH2.");
            }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("Please input a number which corresponds to an enemy.");
        }
    }
```

The error says that it should be an else if, but when I put the if next to it I automatically get 100 errors. What do I do about this?

Comment: Add proper indentation

Comment: Why are you not using switch? It will simplify your solution a lot..

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran: In that part of the code, it looks like the indentation is correct; it's the curly-braces that are wrong.

Comment: missing a `}` before the last `else`

Answer (score 4):

It is always good practice to use if-else if all your if blocks are exclusive. Having said that, above error is due to a missed "}"

```
if (choose == 4) //enemies from the original Kingdom Hearts II
       {
        System.out.println("Please select the enemy race you wish to view:");
        System.out.println("1. Heartless");
        System.out.println("2. Nobodies");
        int enemies_4 = kH.nextInt();

    if (enemies_4 == 1) //Allows the user to select which kinds of Heartless to view from Kingdom Hearts II.
    {
        System.out.println("Please type the number which corresponds to the Heartless enemy type.");
        System.out.println("1. Pureblood");
        System.out.println("2. Emblem");
        System.out.println("3. Gummi");
        int heartless_4 = kH.nextInt();

        if (heartless_4 = 1) //allows the user to view Pureblood Heartless from KH2
        {

        }

        if (heartless_4 == 2) //allows the user to view the Emblem Heartless in KH2
        {

        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number which corresponds to one of the Heartless types KH2.");
        }
    }


    if (enemies_4 == 2) //allows the user to view all of the Nobodies in KH2
    {
        System.out.println("Please type the number which corresponds to the Nobody enemy type.");
        System.out.println("1. Lower");
        System.out.println("2. Gummi");
        int nobodies_4 = kH.nextInt();

        if (nobodies_4 == 1) //Gives the selection of the Lower Nodies in Kingdom Hearts II.
        {

        }

        if (nobodies_4 == 2) //Gives the selection of the Gummi Nobodies, which are ONLY in Kingdom Hearts II
                            //(as well as the Final Mix version of it).
        {

        }

        if (nobodies_4 == 3) //Give the selection of all he members of Organization XIII which appear in
                                //Kingdom Hearts II.
        {

        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number which corresponds to one of the Nobody types KH2.");
        }
     } // You were missing this
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Please input a number which corresponds to an enemy.");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can pare that code down quite a lot so it's more clear where the error is.

Answer (score 0):

There is no end `}` for the condition: `if (enemies_4 == 2)`, you need to add `}`

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like the first if-condition misses the closing parenthesis.

```
if (choose == 4) //enemies from the original Kingdom Hearts II
{

} // This is missing.
```

If this block of condition looks OK to you then you should look for missing closing parenthesis in below block.

```
if (enemies_4 == 2) //allows the user to view all of the Nobodies in KH2
{

} // This is missing.
```

Correct indentation of code is important. If you are using Eclipse or any other IDE, then managing the code indentation is just a click away. Control + Shift + F does this, as long as you have a code selection in a code window.

Also, you should look out to optimize the conditions using `if-else-if` or `switch-case` blocks. Using the correct required block reduces the chances of error.

An example of if-else optimization is depicted below.

[Java if statement checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744679/java-if-statement-checking/21746090#21746090)
[Java if statement checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744679/java-if-statement-checking/21746090#21746090)

Shishir

Answer (score 0):

```
if (choose == 4) //enemies from the original Kingdom Hearts II
       {
        System.out.println("Please select the enemy race you wish to view:");
        System.out.println("1. Heartless");
        System.out.println("2. Nobodies");
        int enemies_4 = kH.nextInt();

    if (enemies_4 == 1) //Allows the user to select which kinds of Heartless to view from Kingdom Hearts II.
    {
        System.out.println("Please type the number which corresponds to the Heartless enemy type.");
        System.out.println("1. Pureblood");
        System.out.println("2. Emblem");
        System.out.println("3. Gummi");
        int heartless_4 = kH.nextInt();

        if (heartless_4 = 1) //allows the user to view Pureblood Heartless from KH2
        {

        }

        if (heartless_4 == 2) //allows the user to view the Emblem Heartless in KH2
        {

        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number which corresponds to one of the Heartless types KH2.");
        }
    }


    if (enemies_4 == 2) //allows the user to view all of the Nobodies in KH2
    {
        System.out.println("Please type the number which corresponds to the Nobody enemy type.");
        System.out.println("1. Lower");
        System.out.println("2. Gummi");
        int nobodies_4 = kH.nextInt();

        if (nobodies_4 == 1) //Gives the selection of the Lower Nodies in Kingdom Hearts II.
        {

        }

        if (nobodies_4 == 2) //Gives the selection of the Gummi Nobodies, which are ONLY in Kingdom Hearts II
                            //(as well as the Final Mix version of it).
        {

        }

        if (nobodies_4 == 3) //Give the selection of all he members of Organization XIII which appear in
                                //Kingdom Hearts II.
        {

        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number which corresponds to one of the Nobody types KH2.");
        }
     }// you miss this 
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Please input a number which corresponds to an enemy.");
    }
}
```